# $\forall\lambda\in \Lambda $, $\int_{F_\lambda}f\ge1$. Prove that $\int_{\cap F_\lambda} f\ge 1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Suppose f is a non-negtive measurable function on $[a,b]$ , and   $\left \{ F_{\lambda}\right \}_{\lambda\in\Lambda} $ is a family of closed sets in $[a,b]$ such that $\forall \lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\Lambda$,we have either $F_{\lambda_1}\subset F_{\lambda_2}$ or $F_{\lambda_2}\subset F_{\lambda_1}$. Also $\forall\lambda\in \Lambda  $, $\int_{F_\lambda}f\ge1$. Prove that $\int_{\cap F_\lambda} f\ge 1$.

If $\Lambda$ is finite or countable,then it's easy to cope with. But if $\Lambda$ is uncountable, it's becoming hard to deal with.I think if we can choose a sequence of decreasing closed sets $\left \{ F_n\right \} $ so that $\forall \lambda,\exists n_0 $ , $F_{n_0}\subset F_\lambda$ and $\cap F_\lambda=\cap F_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}F_n$.But I don't know whether we can select such a sequence from $\left \{ F_{\lambda}\right \}_{\lambda\in\Lambda} $. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Let $m=\inf_{\lambda}\int_{F_{\lambda}} f$. Then $m \geq 1$. There exists a sequence $(\lambda_n)$ such that $\int_{F_{\lambda_n}} f\to m$.

Comment: The statment may be false if $f$ is not integrable in $[a,b]$. For example, define $f(x)=x^{-1}$ for $0<x\leq 1$ and $f(0)=a\geq0$. $F_\lambda=[0,\lambda]$. It is clear that $\int_{F_\lambda}f=\infty\geq1$, however, $\bigcap_\lambda F_\lambda=\{0\}$ and $\int_{\{0\}}f=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is mentioned in the comments, the statement in the OP may not hold when $f$ is not integrable in $[a,b]$.

Assume then that $f\in L_1[a,b]$ and consider the measure $\nu(A)=\int_A f$ for any $A\in\mathscr{B}([a,b])$. Denote $I=[a,b]$, and set $F:=\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda}F_\lambda$. The sets $U_\lambda=I\setminus F_\lambda$ are open sets in $I$, and they form an open cover of $U=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda} U_\lambda=I\setminus \bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda} F_\lambda$. Since $U$, as a topological subspace of $I$, is [Lindelöf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_space) by virtue of being separable, there is a countable sub cover $U_{\lambda_k}$, $(\lambda_k:k\in\mathbb{N})\subset\Lambda$, of $U$. Thus, $U=\bigcup_k U_{\lambda_k}$ and so, $ F=\bigcap_kF_{\lambda_k}$. The rest follows by standard measure theory for the $F_{\lambda_k}$ may be assumed to form a monotone nonincreasing sequence:
$$\mu(F)=\lim_k\nu\big(\bigcap_kF_{\lambda_k}\big)=\lim_k\nu(F_{\lambda_k})\geq1$$
(Here is where the finiteness of $\nu$ plays a role).